# Is there a short and sweet function toString a single jSON object or similar in my example?

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have converted a PHP array into a single selection in a Codeigniter PHP function like so...

```
function check_week($week_array)
{
    $sql = "SELECT X_id FROM products WHERE date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= updated_at;";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $week_array);
    $week = $query->result_array();
    $weeks = json_encode($week[array_rand($week)]);
    return $weeks;
}
```

and I get a return of ...

```
{"X_id":"XXX1AXPJV6"}
```

I have already narrowed this down to one id, so no need to use a loop, I just need the id in one simple move. (so I just want ***XXX1AXPJV6*** as a variable). Also, I did try keeping in PHP for this and Codeigniter was finicky about allowing any conversion to string due to the call to this model is from a library file.

btw, my 1 DAY interval is for testing, it will be 7

An attempt at using...

```
$weeks2 = $weeks[0]['X_id'];
    return $weeks2;
```

...gets error "Cannot use string offset as an array in..."

Comment: So you want `check_week` to return a string? or an array?

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes. specifically "XXX1AXPJV6" a PHP string if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly

```
$weeks = json_encode($week[array_rand($week)]);
```

should be

```
$weeks = reset($week[array_rand($week)]); // returns the value of the first element in the array
```

hope that helps.

Comment: `array_shift` will work as well as reset if you don't mind the original array being altered.

Comment: Looks like reset() does exactly what I need, while array_shift gets me there.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one random row, your SQL should retrieve only one random row.

```
function check_week($week_array)
{
    $sql = "SELECT X_id FROM products WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= updated_at ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $week_array);
    $week = $query->row_array();

    return json_encode($week['X_id']);
}
```

Note the changes in the query, as well as the use of `row_array()` which returns a single key => value array, instead of `result_array()` which returns an array of arrays.

For what it's worth, you could've gotten the result you need by altering this line to:

```
$weeks = json_encode($week[array_rand($week)]['X_id']);
```

But the above is still a more suitable solution. Don't retrieve lots of records if you only need one.

Also, what is the `$week_array` parameter for? You are using it as a query binding, but there are no `?` places for the bindings to go in your query, making it pointless.

Comment: +1 for a very good answer. The only thing is, I wanted to allow for another fork as to doing something with the extra data and a few other things unfortunately I can't share on this one.

Comment: You asked how to have your function return the specified index as a json-encoded string. I'm not a mind reader for how you want to change it down the road. Using `reset()` is a dumb solution (I even showed how you would solve it using your original code).